# fputcsv prints result to screen instead into csv

Tags: php, fputcsv

I am trying to export database data into .csv via php. After a certain length of data it doesn't save the query into a .csv file but displays it on the screen. It looks like it's independent on which records are queried, and it also seems to be independent of any special characters.

```
$handle = fopen("php://output", "w");
fputcsv($handle, array('Name','Text','Link','Category','Price','Package', 'Date of upload','Date of verification','Date of expiry','Status','Clk'));
for ($c=0; $c<$num_rows; $c++)
{
    $row2[$c][0] = iconv("UTF-8","WINDOWS-1257",html_entity_decode( $row2[$c][0] ,ENT_COMPAT,'utf-8'));
    $row2[$c][1] = iconv("UTF-8","WINDOWS-1257",html_entity_decode( $row2[$c][1] ,ENT_COMPAT,'utf-8'));
    fputcsv($handle, array($row2[$c][0], $row2[$c][1], $row2[$c][2], $row2[$c][3], $row2[$c][4], $row2[$c][5], $row2[$c][6], $row2[$c][7], $row2[$c][8], $row2[$c][9], $row2[$c][10]));
}
fclose($handle);

header('Content-Type: text/csv; utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

11 columns, 18 records. With 19 records it's not working.

Am I missing some setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the headers **before** the output!

---

If you convert **to** utf use:

```
iconv("WINDOWS-1257", "UTF-8", ...
```

The order of arguments was wrong

Comment: The header was the problem. I am not using `php://stdout`, I am using `php://output`. With `php://stdout` I get an empty file. Also what is wrong with my utf conversion?

Comment: You convert **to** Windows CP-1257 but setting an utf8 header

Comment: Using `php://output` is perfectly fine, especialy when working with functions that operate on streams. Can you elaborate why in your opinion it does not make sense?

Comment: No, `join` would do the job for very limited set of data. Some data should be put in an encloser and some of the characters escaped to produce valid CSV.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I have admitted this (by removing that part of the comment)

Comment: So what now? After replacing the headers to the top and using iconv the right way, does the problem still exist?

Comment: No. Like I said, the header was the problem. I had to put it before output.

Comment: Ok. After all I admit - again - that the fputcsv action together with php://output was definitely ok. my fault! ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Why do you say I am converting to Windows CP-1257?

Comment: because it should be `iconv($from, $to,..)` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the great answer by @hex2mgl 'set headers before fopen()', you could use output buffering to prevent `fputcsv` from printing directly to the screen instead of into the handle:

```
ob_start();
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$csv = ob_get_clean();
fclose($out);
```

Update:

Just found that the new PHP i/o `php://temp` does a much better job and doesn't require output buffering. Uses memory first (upto 5mb or whatever you specify), then will switch to disk if needed:

```
$fiveMBs = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
$stream = fopen("php://temp/maxmemory:$fiveMBs", 'r+');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
$handle = fopen("php://output", "w");
```

You are getting the handle for the standard output (witch is kind of a file).

Guess you meant:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "w");
```

Comment: This way I get an empty .csv file.

Comment: if you want fputcsv to print to stdout then you question is very misleading. you want browser to save it to *.csv not php

Comment: "I am trying to export database data into .csv" - Why is that misleading?

Comment: this: "fputcsv prints result to screen instead into csv", you want fputcsv to print out its results, you don't want it to write to file, you just want your browser to save server response to file instead of showing it, PHP is server side language.